# Angle of elevation and distance to an object

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

A person walking a straight slope sees (from ground level) an Object across the valley at an angle of $45^{\circ}$, after another 50 meters walking the angle is $60^{\circ}$, How far away is the Object at that moment?

With this much given info I do not know how to approach solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the distance from the object at that moment. Then from geometry of right triangles we have  $$(50+x)\tan 45^\circ=x\tan 60^\circ$$   $$50+x=x\sqrt 3$$ $$x(\sqrt 3-1)=50$$ $$=\frac{50}{\sqrt 3-1}$$
$$=\frac{50(\sqrt 3+1)}{(\sqrt 3-1)(\sqrt 3+1)}$$ $$=\frac{50(\sqrt 3+1)}{2}$$
$$=25(\sqrt 3+1)$$

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\text{Distance from the object}=\color{blue}{25(\sqrt 3+1)\approx 68.3\ m}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint...you need to draw a picture and use trigonometry

If $h$ is the height of the object and $x$ is the distance you want, you have$$\frac hx=\tan60$$ and $$\frac{h}{x+50}=\tan45$$

Eliminate $h$